# How to read pH value

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am trying to read the pH value from a analog pH meter, SEN-01454. From the source code I found, voltage maps to pH value. This is the code:

```
pHArray[pHArrayIndex++]=analogRead(SensorPin);
      if(pHArrayIndex==ArrayLenth)pHArrayIndex=0;
      voltage = avergearray(pHArray, ArrayLenth)*5.0/1024;
      pHValue = 3.5*voltage+Offset;
      samplingTime=millis();
```

But then the value is not correct. So how do i actually do it.

The [example code from Wiki page](http://dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/PH_meter%28SKU:_SEN0161%29) for product.

Comment: What value do you expect?

Comment: the value of the liquid

Comment: ok a bit more specific, what liquid are you testing. Do you know what that liquids' pH is, this is of use if you are calibrating it. If you are testing a liquid and don't know its pH before testing you might actually be getting the right value.

Comment: Sodium Hydroxide which is pH value of 12.

Comment: and the value you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

This is SOME of the code. We are missing the `avergearray()` function.. I suspect you're taking one reading and averaging it with both old & future ones, but this code clearly is meant to sit in a loop..

From another [source](http://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=1454), I got this:

```
/*
# This sample codes is for testing the pH meter V1.0.
 # Editor : YouYou
 # Date   : 2013.10.12
 # Ver    : 0.1
 # Product: pH meter
 # SKU    : SEN0161
*/

#define SensorPin 0          //pH meter Analog output to Arduino Analog Input 0
unsigned long int avgValue;  //Store the average value of the sensor feedback
float b;
int buf[10],temp;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  Serial.println("Ready");    //Test the serial monitor
}
void loop()
{
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)       //Get 10 sample value from the sensor for smooth the value
  { 
    buf[i]=analogRead(SensorPin);
    delay(10);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++)        //sort the analog from small to large
  {
    for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
    {
      if(buf[i]>buf[j])
      {
        temp=buf[i];
        buf[i]=buf[j];
        buf[j]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
  avgValue=0;
  for(int i=2;i<8;i++)                      //take the average value of 6 center sample
    avgValue+=buf[i];
  float phValue=(float)avgValue*5.0/1024/6; //convert the analog into millivolt
  phValue=3.5*phValue;                      //convert the millivolt into pH value
  Serial.print("    pH:");  
  Serial.print(phValue,2);
  Serial.println(" ");
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);       
  delay(800);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); 

}
```

which reads in the array first and then averages it. Is this what your code does? If so, what sort of errors are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error. But i can't get the correct value of the pH

Comment: So what values do you get instead? And, with respect, there probably is an error - or it would work!